# how to get python to recognize more than one letter at a time

Tags: python

So my current assignment is to make a cipher using a double encoding. So I have one variable that is a list of letters aa to zz. Another variable is a copy of that same list shuffled. I then inserted the Alpha pair as the key in a dictionary and the pair copy as the value in the dictionary. The issue I have run into now is getting it to look at one more than one letter in the message at a time.

I tried just creating a new variable and a for loop to simply run through it but it is only looking at one letter at a time

```py
import random

alpha= 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz '
alphalist= list(alpha)
alphapair= []

for let1 in alphalist:
    for let2 in alphalist:
        pair = let1+let2
        alphapair.append(pair)

paircopy= alphapair[:]

random.seed(6767)
random.shuffle(paircopy)

incoding_cipher=dict(zip(alphapair,paircopy))

message=input("Please type the message you would like to encode: ") #optional to allow for an input to encode
message= message.lower()
incoded_message=''

for let in message:
    incoded_message += incoding_cipher[let]

print(incoded_message)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this will work for you:

```
msgtemp = (message + ' ') if (len(message) % 2) else message
for i in range(0, len(msgtemp), 2):
    pair = msgtemp[i] + msgtemp[i + 1]
    incoded_message += incoding_cipher[pair]
```

This adds a space to the end of the message if it is of odd length.

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm reading this right but the problem isn't creating the pairs. The problem is I'm trying I have the message I'm trying to encode using them. like say if I use the word "hello" it's only looking at the letter "h" and not "he" so then it can find he in the variable list and replace it with the value of the dictionary.

Comment: So you mean like my modified answer?  I applied the same technique to your message encoding.

Comment: yea sure my next goal was to figure out how to do that

Comment: ok, now it will handle odd message lengths, with the last pair ending in a space. - let me know if you want any help understanding this code

Comment: Sorry...what seems to be wrong?  That's what's in my IDE, along with just a definition of 'message'.

Comment: ...oops...I took out your domain code.  Better now?

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
for let in message:
    incoded_message += incoding_cipher[let]
```

to:

```
for first, second in zip(message[::2], message[1::2] + ' ' * (len(message) % 2)):
    key = first + second
    incoded_message += incoding_cipher[key]
```